# GSA sorting over all pages

Tags: google-search, google-search-appliance

Does Google search provide sorting option on metadata. I have requirement that suggest to sort contents on there popularity and place them using pagination. We are pushing download/view count on each content to GSA as metadata.

All the results that are returned in the search result are placed in order by download/view count, so that the first page would show the most used content and then in following pages we would start to see the less frequently used content.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

nv185001,

Based upon the [documentation](http://goo.gl/4Q9Wl) the GSA will only perform a sort on content relevance and date. You may attempt to develop a OneBox that queries a source for the top downloaded content based upon the search query term. This would at least incorporate the desired results into your FrontEnd.

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is indeed possible to sort by meta-data in GSA

Refer https://www.google.com/support/enterprise/static/gsa/docs/admin/72/gsa_doc_set/xml_reference/request_format.html#1083224

Use sort=meta:metaname parameter to do this.

Bumping the old thread since the previous answer was incorrect.